# Filtering aggregated referenced nodes

Tags: views, entities, css-js-aggregation

I have two content types and a view that I want to count the number of Requests per Trial. The thing is I want to filter the Requests in a view of the Trials. Here's the problem laid out:

Content Types: 
 - "Request"
 - "Trial"

"Request" has an entity reference field that references "Trial." (user can request a trial).

Aggregated view that lists the Trials with the number of Requests referenced to it. This is working fine now, but I need to filter the number of requests by workflow state.

`___________________________________________________________
| Trial                              | Number of Requests |
| Example Trial Name                 | 10                 |
| Another one                        | 2                  |`

The trick is that I want to filter the number of Requests according to their workflow state. I can filter the Trials in their own view, but I'm not sure how to "pre-"filter the referenced nodes.

Comment: Have you added the "relationship" part under the advanced tab in the view?

Comment: I did add relationships. After reviewing this with a friend I think I can't do what I want without a custom template. The solution, I think, is to make a view on the Requests, list the Trials linked with each Request, then custom template the comma separated list of values into a table, then aggregate.(Not sure how that last step happens). A rough 10 hour estimate and the client decided to find another solution.

Comment: Ok... but if I understand your q correctly you should be able to do it fairly easily. Add a screengrab of your view with the advanced tab open so we can see your full settings, and will try to help